# Solr: Search in multiple fields BUT STOP if documents match was found

Tags: lucene, solr

I want to search in multiple fields in Solr.
(In know the concept of the copy-fields and I know the (e)dismax search handler.)

So I have an orderd list of fields, I want the terms to be searched against.
1.) SKU
2.) Name
3.) Description
4.) Summary
and so on.

Now, when the query matches a term, let's say in the SKU field, I want this match and no further searches in the proceeding fields.

Only, if there are NO matches at all in the first field (SKU field), the second field (in this case "name") should be used and so on.

Is this possible with Solr?
Do I have to implement my own Lucene Search Handler for this?

Any advice is welcome!

Thank you,
Bernhard

Answer (score 2):

I think your case requires executing 4 different searches. If you implement you very own SearchHandler you could avoid penalty of search result accumulation in 4 different request. Which means, you would send one query, and custom SearchHandler would execute 4 searches and prepare one result set.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this approach. If I dig down into the sources and do the coding, a new question appears: Should I rather implement this as a LuceneSearchHandler or on top of the Solr Java Classes? What are the advantages/disadvantages? Thank you!

Comment: Building on top of Solr API should be easier and less invasive if you are already using Solr. You can then configure additional seeting of custom search handler along with the rest of Solr configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is right you want to rank the results based on the order of the fields. If so then you can just use  standard query like

**q=sku:(query)^4 OR name:(query)^3 OR description:(query)^2 OR summary:(query)**

this will rank the results by the order of the fields.

Hope is helps.

Comment: I like this idea but it doesn't meet all the requirements of the OP.