# Lucene: how to stop searching in the current document after the first match

Tags: java, lucene

The title might be somewhat ambiguous, but bear with me (The only similar question I could find was [Solr: Search in multiple fields BUT STOP if documents match was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783829/solr-search-in-multiple-fields-but-stop-if-documents-match-was-found), but that did not provide any solutions). I have the following structure for my lucene documents:

```
FieldA (Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED), primary identification of an entity
FieldB (Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED), secondary identification(s) of an entity
```

`FieldA` could for example contain a string like `car`, where `FieldB` could contain strings like `automobile`, `vehicle`, etc. There can be multiple `FieldB` fields in the document. The index analyzer is a `StandardAnalyzer`, the search analyzer is a `KeywordAnalyzer` (that seemed to yield the best result, not sure if it is the best approach). The identifier in `FieldA` is of higher importance then the identifier(s) in `FieldB`.

Let's say the index contains 3 documents (with `FieldA | FieldB` fields):

```
"car"       | "vehicle" "automobile"
"car parts" | "parts, car"
"car shop"  | "shop, car"
```

So far, so good. Now where the problem lies:

When querying for `"car"`, I would like to see the following result (scores are made up):

```
car, score 1.0
car parts, score 0.9
car shop, score 0.9
```

The document with the `FieldA` value of "car" should show up first, since `FieldA` is considered more important, and the query matches that value best. In reality, the following happens:

```
car parts, score 0.625
car shop, score 0.625
car, score 0.5073969
```

`searcher.explain()` outputs the following: (left the explain for "car shop" out, since it is the same as "car parts")

```
Explain: 0.625 = (MATCH) max of:
  0.31712303 = (MATCH) weight(fielda:car in 0), product of:
    0.71231794 = queryWeight(fielda:car), product of:
      0.71231794 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=3)
      1.0 = queryNorm
    0.4451987 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(fielda:car in 0), product of:
      1.0 = tf(termFreq(fielda:car)=1)
      0.71231794 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=3)
      0.625 = fieldNorm(field=fielda, doc=0)
  0.625 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(fieldb:car in 0), product of:
    1.0 = tf(termFreq(fieldb:car)=1)
    1.0 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=3)
    0.625 = fieldNorm(field=fieldb, doc=0)
Explain: 0.5073969 = (MATCH) max of:
  0.5073969 = (MATCH) weight(fielda:car in 0), product of:
    0.71231794 = queryWeight(fielda:car), product of:
      0.71231794 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=3)
      1.0 = queryNorm
    0.71231794 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(fielda:car in 0), product of:
      1.0 = tf(termFreq(fielda:car)=1)
      0.71231794 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=3)
      1.0 = fieldNorm(field=fielda, doc=0)
```

TL;DR: with the two fields, boosting FieldA will not help because all 3 documents will get boosted. How to get lucene to rank the closest match ("car" in this example") as the highest? i.e. how to stop searching in the current document after the (more important) match in `FieldA` is encountered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NOT syntax.

`a:car^2 (+b:car -a:car)`

This way ones with matches in b will be ignored unless they fail to match a.

Comment: This solves the problem where a term occurs on both fields, but as always there was an underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in **fieldb** car is only found in two of the three terms, whereas in **fielda** car is found in all three terms. So a match to car in fieldb scores higher because it has a higher idf (1.0 compared to 0.7123174)

The value of a match is essentially:

> idf * idf * fieldnorm * tf

where fieldnorm is

```
lengthnorm * fieldboost
```

so you can see idf is pretty important.

Actually if you did boost field a that would work, because matches on field a would get aboost compared to matches on fieldb, and in your example it is a match on fieldb that is ranked higher.